# SYNflood攻撃とiptablesの設定について

Tags: linux, centos, ubuntu, iptables

[このページ](https://help.sakura.ad.jp/hc/ja/articles/206208121-iptables%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)に「SYNflood攻撃と思われる接続を破棄する」ための設定として

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

と書いてありました。

しかし、この設定だと「新規接続なのにSYNパケットでないものはDROPする」という設定のように思えます。

SYNflood攻撃というのは[Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood)によると、
「SYNパケットを送信した後、返ってくるSYN-ACKパケットを無視して放置する」
という攻撃方法のようなので、上記の「SYNパケットで無い」ものを対象にしているiptablesの設定と噛み合っていない気がします。

本当に、この設定はSYNflood攻撃の対処法になっているのでしょうか？

(hashlimitやsynクッキーを使うべきとかそういう話ではなく、単純にこの設定がSYNflood攻撃を想定していないように見えたという話です。)

Comment: これは、SYNflood 攻撃の対処法というよりは stealth scan(FIN scan や XMAS scan(FIN、URG、PSH on))対策の様に見えます。

Comment: @metropolis コメント有り難うございます。やはり`SYNflood`対策では無さそうですよね。ただ、`! --syn`は正確には`SYN,RST,ACK`の内の`RST`か`ACK`のビットが立っているかどうかを調べるもののようなので、`FIN SCAN`や`XMAS SCAN`にも効果が無い気もします。